# Arcgis javascript TOC with secure services

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have secured map services with AGS. I also have the proxy.config, proxy.ashx, and web.config in my application. My map layers display OK using the proxy. When I try to display my legend using the proxy map layers, a login dialog shows up and the legend does not display. If I enter my username and password the legend displays. When I use unsecured services from an AGS server the legend displays fine.

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with you proxy, check if it is getting the legend request. If not, you could configure the proxy url in esriConfig properties to always use proxy.

```
 esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "<url_to_proxy>"
 esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when i change esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true, error appear    n {message: "Unable to load proxy/proxy.ashx?http://www.arcgis.…est/portals/self?f=json&culture=en-us status: 500", response: Object, status: 500, responseText: "<html>
↵    <head>
↵        <title>Configuration E…e(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
↵-->", xhr: XMLHttpRequest…}

Comment: esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = 'proxy/proxy.ashx';
 esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true;

Comment: Can you share the "proxy map url" that you have used to create the map layer.

Comment: which proxy that you want to see?proxy.config file?